# Show that every totally bounded metric space is a bounded metric space

Tags: general-topology

I might be overthinking this, but if a metric space is totally bounded, then the distance between any two point is less than epsilon for all epsilon. That implies that the distance between any two point is 0. Now does this mean that the space has only one point? Because according to the axioms of metric space, distance between two point is 0 iff they are the same point. So if the case has only one point, then it trivially bounded.

Comment: For all $\varepsilon$ there is some $n$ such that there are $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ such that for all $t$ there is some $k$ such that $d(t,x_k)<\varepsilon$ $$$$ versus $$$$ There is some $n$ such that there are some $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ such that for all $\varepsilon$ and for all $t$ there is some $k$ such that $d(x_k,t)<\varepsilon$ $$$$ versus $$$$ There is some $n$ such that there are some $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ such that there is some $k$ such that, for all $\varepsilon$ and for all $t$, $d(x_k,t)<\varepsilon$. Et cetera, you find yours.

Comment: " if a metric space is totally bounded, then the distance between any two point is less than epsilon for all epsilon" no...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total boundedness only tells you that there is an $\epsilon -$ net for each $\epsilon >0$. But the number of points in the net depends on $\epsilon$. So it doesn't follow that the space has only one point.

If $\{B(x_1,\epsilon), B(x_2,\epsilon),...,B(x_n,\epsilon)\}$ cover $X$ then, given any $x,y \in X$, we can pick $i,j$ such that $x \in B(x_i,\epsilon),$ and $y \in B(x_j,\epsilon)$. It follows that $d(x,y) \leq d(x,x_i)+d(x_i,x_j)+d(x_j,y)\leq 2\epsilon+\max \{d(x_p,x_q): 1\leq p,q \leq n\}$. So $X$ is bounded. But we have no control over the behavior of the bound as $\epsilon \to 0$.